# iterate and write separately linestrings (generate_series)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, plpgsql

I have a table full of a mix of polygons and multipolygons and I would like to run a single function on to break them into LineStrings (or MultiLinestrings).

My problem - I am currently returning a set with ... no geometry (?)...

The function currently looks like this...(final based on Mike T. help)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LinesFromPoly2(polygon geometry) 
RETURNS SETOF geometry_dump AS 
$BODY$DECLARE 
 m integer; 
 g geometry;
 p geometry_dump%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN
    FOR m IN SELECT generate_series(1, ST_NumGeometries($1)) LOOP 
      p.path[1] := m;
      p.geom := ST_Boundary(ST_GeometryN($1, m));
     RETURN NEXT p;
     END LOOP;
  RETURN; 
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

CALL:

```
SELECT id, name, LinesFromPoly2(the_geom)
  FROM public.poly_and_multipoly;
```

RETURNS:

```
1|A|({1},)
2|B|({1},)
2|B|({2},)
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE poly_and_multipoly (
  "id" SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" char(1) NOT NULL,
  "the_geom" geometry NOT NULL
);
-- add data, A is a polygon, B is a multipolygon
INSERT INTO poly_and_multipoly (name, the_geom) VALUES (
    'A', 'POLYGON((7.7 3.8,7.7 5.8,9.0 5.8,7.7 3.8))'::geometry
    ), (
    'B',
    'MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0),(1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1)), ((-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1)))'::geometry
);
```

Comment: You should be able to do all of this without using any functions, using a couple of CTEs (with queries). If you want help with that, could you post a few rows of example input geometries.

Comment: @JohnBarça ok, added it above. I think I'm going to still try to keep it a function (I already know how to do this the query path - as shown above). I'm a little wary of adding more sub-queries to my workflow...

Comment: Fair enough. As you are using ST_GeometryN, you don't need ST_Dump at all, as far as I can see.   `g := ST_Boundary(ST_GeometryN($1, m));`

Comment: @JohnBarça good catch. Weirdly, now I am getting something - a set with no geom ....(never seen that happen before).

Comment: @JohnBarça - just in case you were curious... I was using ST_Dump to break the MultiLineStrings into LineStrings - but at this stage, I can let that slide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom function to do what you want. For instance, try just accessing the two members of [`ST_Dump`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) (`path` and `geom`):

```
SELECT id, name,
  (ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(the_geom))).path[1],
  ST_AsText((ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(the_geom))).geom)
FROM poly_and_multipoly;

 id | name | path |                 st_astext
----+------+------+-------------------------------------------
  1 | A    |      | LINESTRING(7.7 3.8,7.7 5.8,9 5.8,7.7 3.8)
  2 | B    |    1 | LINESTRING(0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0)
  2 | B    |    2 | LINESTRING(1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1)
  2 | B    |    3 | LINESTRING(-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1)
(4 rows)
```

Or one [MULTI]LINESTRING per geometry part:

```
SELECT id, name,
  (ST_Dump(the_geom)).path[1],
  ST_AsText(ST_Boundary((ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom))
FROM poly_and_multipoly;

 id | name | path |                          st_astext
----+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | A    |      | LINESTRING(7.7 3.8,7.7 5.8,9 5.8,7.7 3.8)
  2 | B    |    1 | MULTILINESTRING((0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0),(1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1))
  2 | B    |    2 | LINESTRING(-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1)
(3 rows)
```

But if you did want to use your `LinesFromPolygon2` function, the fix is simple: assign the geometry to `p.geom`, not `g`, i.e.

```
p.geom := ST_Boundary(ST_GeometryN($1, m));
```